# How to use ArrayField in Tortoise-ORM using PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi, tortoise-orm, postico

In Tortoise-ORM connected to PostgreSQL, how to use ArrayField to
store values in it and perform CRUD operations on the FastAPI-admin interface?

I have used this:

```
hashtag = ArrayField (element type = "text").
```

But I am not able to store #abcd, #wxyz in this. How to handle this issue? Please explain and provide proper syntax also if needed to store in the array.

Instead, it breaks every character and stores that in an array when I create it on the FastAPI-admin interface. For Ex -> `{"#","a","b","c","d"}` is created while I need this, `{"#abcd"}`.
But when I do it directly in the database, i.e., PostgreSQL is monitored by Postico.

I have tried the above code, but it does not work as expected. I was expecting that it should provide a proper array format, but it breaks each character and then stores it in the array.

Comment: could you explain/show how you are entering the data?